# Why our game never appeared in the new section of the appstore?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

We released a game 4 days ago (Thursday), [Junction Action Arcade](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id680228568), its categories are action and arcade,
and I've been looking in the appstore in the section "Games -> Action -> New", in tha USA store, and it never appeared there.

Doesn't every new release appear in that section sometime? Or how does that work?

Answer (score 1):

You actually want to look in featured games->action->paid which allows you to sort everything by release date or name.

The "new" category is horribly broken or useless for some reason and only seems to contain what apple wants to be there. Also the "new" apps section contains a lot of items that aren't even new! Changes are in order with ios7.

Unfortunately this isn't going to be clear to your actual potential users.

---

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'd say if the section "contain[s] what [A]pple wants to be there" then it probably isn't broken, it just probably isn't doing what you'd like it to do. Whether that's intuitive or not is another question.

Comment: @tubedogg Yeah i suppose you're right; poor word choice on my part. I guess what I mean is it's either broken or it's a poor design choice.

Comment: I really have no idea what apple wants to be there -- i was more thinking along the lines of whatever apple puts there. Those sections appear as if they aren't often often updated and much of the content is a far stretch from new.  It's hard to imagine that as an intended design.